# WebMatrix Beta 2 is unavailable for Download

Tags: webmatrix

WebMatrix 2 Beta is unavailable for Download. The [link](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/next/) is installing 1.0 or 1.1 version.

Comment: It's pointing to the Beta for me.

Comment: @marcind, It's just pointing. If you start downloading/installing, it will download/install 1.0 or 1.1. I have tried more than 20 times.

Comment: @marcind, it seems to be fixed by team members, http://forums.iis.net/t/1187078.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get WebMatrix 2 Beta, it appears you need Web Platform Installer 4.0

Unfortunately the link on http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/next/ **was** giving the launcher for Web Platform Installer 3.0 which only served up WebMatrix 1.11

Their site still references Web Platform Installer 3.0, but it will upgrade you to Web PI 4.0 and then provide you with the option to install WebMatrix 2 Beta.

Just make sure the link to download is pointing at:
[a http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=webmatrix&prerelease=true](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=webmatrix&prerelease=true&mode=new)&**mode=new**

That last part of the link I have **bolded** was missing as recent as yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @cusman, that fix is correct (I posted that on the WebMatrix forums (here: http://forums.iis.net/1166.aspx and specifically here: http://forums.iis.net/t/1187078.aspx).  I've made a fix so users should NOT have to use the workaround provided above (for English users that is)

We are looking to get